# How to remove text between variables

Tags: python

I currently have a string that has variables in it.

```
domain.com/?hello=randomtext&thingy=randotext2&stuff=1231kjh
```

I'm trying to delete

```
&thingy=(all text that is in here)
```

The order might not always be that, and the text after the `=` will change.

I started doing something like this, but I feel there has to be quicker alternative:

```
cleanlist = []
variables = url.split('&')
for t in variables:
    if not t.split('=', 1)[0] == 'thingy':
        cleanlist.append(t.split('=', 1)[0])
```

Comment: Why not use Python's standard library functionality for handling URLs?

Comment: do you want just the variable name or you want to rebuild the url without the `thingy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can substitute using regex.

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(&thingy=.*)&')
test_str = u"domain.com/?hello=randomtext&thingy=randotext2&stuff=1231kjh"
subst = u"&"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)

>>> result
u'domain.com/?hello=randomtext&stuff=1231kjh'
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know Python, but from experience with other programming languages, the question I think you should have asked is "How do you parse a URL in Python?" or "How do you parse a url query string in Python?"

Just Googling this I got the following info that may help:

```
from urlparse import urlparse
o = urlparse('domain.com/?hello=randomtext&thingy=randotext2&stuff=1231kjh')
q = urlparse.parse_qs(o.query, true)
>>> q.hello

randomtext

>>> q.thingy

randomtext2
```

Once you parse the URL and query string, just grab what you want.

Answer (score -1):

If I get your question right then you're trying the delete all the  string which is `"&thingy=randotext2&stuff=1231kjh "`

This can be easily achieved by doing something like this:

```
current_str = "domain.com/?hello=randomtext&thingy=randotext2&stuff=1231kjh" 
cursor = current_str.find("&thingy=")
clean_str = current_str[:cursor]
```

Now the `clean_str` variable is what you're looking for.

This will give a clean result which is only:

```
domain.com/?hello=randomtext
```

Comment: I'm trying to delete just ```&thingy=randotext2``` and keep the variable after

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to delete only a query string argument value, such as `&thingy=`, in a regular expression it's like this:

```
import re
domain = "domain.com/?hello=randomtext&thingy=randotext2&stuff=1231kjh"
x = re.sub(r'(&thingy=)[^&]*(&?.*)$', r'\1\2', domain)
```

Never mind what's followed after the given one.